# Changing Bootstrap Tooltip Message in Angular 16 Disables Dropdowns

Tags: tooltip, bootstrap-5, angular16

I am currently working on a project in Angular 16 with Bootstrap 5.3, and I'm facing an issue related to tooltips and dropdowns. I have a tooltip that I want to update with a different message dynamically. Initially, I tried using the HTML attributes, but that didn't work as expected. To work around this, I attempted to modify the tooltip content using TypeScript, which did change the message successfully. However, this solution introduced an unexpected problem – it disabled all the dropdowns on my page.

I try:

```
<span class="input-status">
    <i data-bs-toggle="tooltip" id="status-warehouse" data-bs-placement="top"
        data-bs-custom-class="custom-tooltip"
        [attr.data-bs-title]="inputs.warehouse.message"
        [attr.data-original-title]="inputs.warehouse.message"
        class="fa fa-check"></i>
</span>
```

This doesn't work, so I try whit JQuery:

```
$('#'+idTooltip).attr('data-original-title', message).tooltip();
```

And doesn´t work too, so I attempted to use the Bootstrap Tooltip module in TypeScript like this:

```
changeTooltip(idTooltip: string, message: string) {
    const tooltip = Tooltip.getInstance("#" + idTooltip);
    tooltip.setContent({ '.tooltip-inner': message });
}
```

This approach successfully changes the tooltip message, but it disables all dropdowns. Any ideas on how to make this work without affecting the dropdown functionality?

Comment: Don't select elements by ID in angular - There's probably **tons** of elements with `id="status-warehouse"` - [Here's](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-webcontainer-template-6msp4x-v8k9vy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts) a proper example of how to show bootstrap tooltips in angular